# Higher Order componnt does not dilver InputList

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, higher-order-components

```
export const HOC = (WrappedComponent) => {


  const { register, control, handleSubmit, reset, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      test: [{ firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Luo" }]
    }
  });
  const { fields, append, prepend, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "test"
  });

  return (
    <form>
   
      <ul>
        {fields.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <WrappedComponent
              item={item}
              removeindex={remove}
              index={index}
              {...register(`test.${index}.firstName`)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <section>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            append({ firstName: "appendBill" });
          }}
        >
          Append
        </button>
      </section>
    </form>
  );
};
export default HOC 

const InputList = props => {

 
    return (
        <li key={props.item.id}>
         <input   {...props}  ></input>
         <button onClick={() => props.removeindex(props.index)} type="button" >Delete</button>
          
      </li>
        
    );
};
export default HOC(InputList)
```

Above I created Higher order Component with React   hooks and React FORM hook  in order to render input List component. But I get the following error

**Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function
component.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Higher Order Component (HOC) isn't returning a React component and the React hook logic isn't in a the React component you are trying to return.

HOCs typically have a signature that looks like this at a minimum:

```
const withHOC = WrappedComponent => props => <JSX />
```

HOCs are really just Higher Order Functions, but in the world of React it's a function that returns a React component. If the above "curried" view is a bit difficult to grok, perhaps this expanded view will help:

```
const withHOC = WrappedComponent => {
  // some HOC logic
  return props => {
    // some fancy component logic
    return (
      <WrappedComponent {...props} {/* ...HOC props? */} />
    );
  };
};
```

In your code's case you are missing the "inner" anonymous React component. Don't forget to add a React key to the components you are mapping so when elements are removed or the underlying field data array is sorted/mutated/etc that React's reconciliation process can function correctly, use the mapped item's `id` property.

```
export const HOC = WrappedComponent => {
  return props => {
    const { register, control, handleSubmit, reset, watch } = useForm({
      defaultValues: {
        test: [{ firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Luo" }]
      }
    });

    const { fields, append, prepend, remove } = useFieldArray({
      control,
      name: "test"
    });

    return (
      <form>
        <ul>
          {fields.map((item, index) => (
            <WrappedComponent
              key={item.id} // <-- add React key for deletion reconciliation
              item={item}
              removeindex={remove}
              index={index}
              {...register(`test.${index}.firstName`)}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
        <section>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => append({ firstName: "appendBill" })}
          >
            Append
          </button>
        </section>
      </form>
    );
  };
};
```

[image: Edit higher-order-componnt-does-not-dilver-inputlist]

Comment: @KasunWickramanayake You need to use a React key on the `WrappedComponent`s that you are mapping. Basically React is using the child's index and you are mutating the array, so you are really just seeing that the array length was shortened and now the last element is no longer rendered. Do the `fields` you are mapping have any unique properties that you could use to uniquely identify them? If so, let us know what that is and I can update answer accordingly. If not, then I can also update my answer with a suggestion that I think could work for you.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-dewdney-5p6yi?file=/src/index.js
What I want is when the delete button is clicked the row the delete button is click has to be removed. ex if i delete the second row the second row has to be deleted.But in this case it always delete the last row.@Drew Reese

Comment: @KasunWickramanayake Ok, I see. Please see updated answer and linked fork of your sandbox.

Comment: @Dres sorry to bother you.I have a doubt.In React Form documentation they have not provide any  any ID .But it works perfectly fine there.Is there any particular reason for that.If we provide child components have unique key why we need to have unique id to delete the component
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-ssugn

Comment: @KasunWickramanayake Ah, you know what, it looks like react-form was already using GUIDs under the hood.If you console log the inputs's props you'll see each item still has an `id` property. I updated my answer and linked codesandbox to reflect this. The `item.id` as the React key is still necessary, but to address the rest of your doubt, the key use is entirely a React thing, it uses the key to match components from the previous render and potentially bail out of rerendering children components if it can.