# cannot extract the data from React from Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

**member-registration-form.tsx**

```
      import OrderList from "../components/orderList";
      import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";
      const MemberRegistration = () => {
          const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
           
          });
        
          
        
          const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
          const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");
         
          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
              <OrderList />
              <input type="submit" />
            </form>
          );
        };
        
       export default MemberRegistration;
```

**orderList.tsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import hoc from "./hoc";
import { TextField, Stack } from "@mui/material";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
 const OrderDetails = (props) => {

  
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={1} >
 
      <TextField   {...props.register(`test.${props.index}.x`)} ></TextField>
      <TextField   {...props.register(`test.${props.index}.y`)}></TextField>
      <TextField   {...props.register(`test.${props.index}.z`)}></TextField>
      <button onClick={() => props.removeindex(props.index)} type="button">
      Delete
      </button>
    </Stack>
  );
};
export default hoc(OrderDetails);
```

**hoc.tsx**

```
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
    const hoc = (WrappedComponent) => {
      return (props) => {
        const { register, control, handleSubmit, reset, watch } = useForm({
          defaultValues: {
            test: [{ firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Luo" }]
          }
        });
    
        const { fields, append, prepend, remove } = useFieldArray({
          control,
          name: "test"
        });
    
        return (
          <form >
            <ul>
              {fields.map((item, index) => (
                <WrappedComponent
                  key={item.id}
                  item={item}
                  removeindex={remove}
                  index={index} 
                  register = {register}
                />
              ))}
            </ul>
            <section>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                  append({ firstName: "appendBill", lastName: "appendLuo" });
                }}
              >
                append
              </button>
    
            
            </section>
          </form>
        );
      };
    };
    export default hoc;
```

On the above code I wrapped the **OrderList component** inside the **hoc**(higher order component) to display dynamically generated content .**member-registration-form.tsx** page is the page where component is render.It works perfectly fine as i expected.But I could not extract the data entered  when the submit button is clicked.It gives me an empty array.

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/higher-order-componnt-does-not-dilver-inputlist-forked-qp110?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You should put your imports in the examples too. Theres no connection to MemberRegistration component, so I assume you render your hoc in <InputList />, which may be where your issue is, but I think we are missing it as example.

Comment: i added the imports.Thank you

Comment: You still need to show us your InputList component (where your hoc is rendered I assume)

Comment: I change the code .thank you

Comment: You have two "<" infront of OrderList, there should be only one. It should work if TextField is accepted by the form.

Comment: actually it is copying error. sorry.but it does not give the desired out put

Comment: @cnps https://codesandbox.io/s/higher-order-componnt-does-not-dilver-inputlist-forked-qp110?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 2 different instances of the `useForm()` hook. The reason your not getting any data when you submit your form is because you are using the `handleSubmit()` function from the first instance in your form component and then you are registering fields with the second instance in your hoc component. You either need to pass the register function down as a prop or you can pass the whole useform function down but you can't strike up 2 different instances and expect them to communicate with each other.  You could do something like the following:

member registration form

```
import OrderList from "./orderList";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";
import * as React from "react";

const MemberRegistration = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    amount: "",
    password: "",
    weight: "",
    weightRange: "",
    showPassword: false
  });

  const {register, control, handleSubmit} = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      test: [{ firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Luo" }]
    }
  })

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <OrderList register={register} control={control}/>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default MemberRegistration;
```

order list

```
import * as React from "react";

import hoc from "./hoc";
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912689/higher-order-componnt-does-not-dilver-inputlist
 */
const OrderDetails = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input {...props.register(`test.${props.index}.firstName`)} />

      <button onClick={() => props.removeindex(props.index)} type="button">
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default hoc(OrderDetails);
```

hoc

```
import { useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import * as React from "react";

const hoc = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    const { register, control } = props;

    const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
      control,
      name: "test"
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {fields.map((item, index) => (
            <WrappedComponent
              key={item.id}
              item={item}
              removeindex={remove}
              index={index}
              register={register}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
        <section>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              append({ firstName: "appendBill", lastName: "appendLuo" });
            }}
          >
            append
          </button>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default hoc;
```

Comment: Hi thank you for you answer.but when I click the submit button it only gives me default values.
https://codesandbox.io/s/higher-order-componnt-does-not-dilver-inputlist-forked-qp110?file=/src/member-registration-form.js

Comment: Like I said in my answer you can't use 2 different instances of the `useForm()` hook an you are still trying to do so. It won't work. Here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/higher-order-componnt-does-not-dilver-inputlist-forked-nku0n